# React render { [key: string]: object }

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  links: {
    [key: string]: Link
  };
}

interface Link {
  name: string;
  url: string;
  icon: string;
}

export default function Header(props: Props) {
  const { links } = props;
  return (
    <header className="header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          { links ?
            Object.entries(links).map((link: any) =>
              link + ' ' + link.url
            )
            : ''
           }
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

<Header links={
  { "home": {
      name: 'Home',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'faHome'
    }
  }
}/>
```

I am getting `home,[object Object] undefined` rendered but how can I render `home /home`?

In the end it should be a `<a href={link.url}>link.name</a>` element!

Or is there generally a better way to do the interface/component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.entries` gives you the key-value pair an a touple. Since you only need to the values, you can simply use `Object.values`

```
export default function Header(props: Props) {
  const { links } = props;
  return (
    <header className="header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          { links ?
            Object.values(links).map((link: any) =>
              <a href={link.url}>{link.name}</a>
            )
            : ''
           }
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```

With `Object.entries` it would look like

```
export default function Header(props: Props) {
  const { links } = props;
  return (
    <header className="header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          { links ?
            Object.entries(links).map(([key, link]) =>
              <a href={link.url}>{link.name}</a>
            )
            : ''
           }
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```